# How to reliable get Chrome Devtools working with Cordova+Crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, developer-tools, crosswalk

About once every few months I have to put days and hours in getting `Chrome Developer Tools` to work again with `Cordova/Crosswalk` App on real devices.

Please note:

- I have `STFW` (too many newbie questions driving out more specific ones)
- I have `RTFM` (Cordova docs suck for advanced usage; troubleshooting not really exists)
- **It already worked before.**
- **I didnt change anything in Cordova/node/gradle/crosswalk environment** (like updates, new plugins, or in general any changes outsite of assets/www)
- I'm developing with Cordova for almost 2 years now. (so I'm experienced)

What I tried/checked:

1. **USB debugging IS enabled** on mobile device
2. Added in Crosswalk src: `XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true)`
3. Set `debuggable` in Android Manifest: `<application android:debuggable="true" ...>`
4. `adb devices` **lists device**:

   ```
   C:\Users\abcdefg>adb devices
   List of devices attached
   0123456789ABCDEF        device
   ```
5. `chrome://inspect/#devices` **lists Chrome Pages on device, but not Cordova-Crosswalk-App** (which was running in foreground when screen was shot):
    [chrome://inspect/#devices Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRdCR.png)
6. Tested on **two different Android devices** (*both* worked 1 week before):

   - One Plus Two (Android 5.0.0)
   - Custom Chinese Handheld (barcode scanner integrated) (Android 4.2.2)
7. Tried to start Developer Tools with **latest GapDebug** (same effect as in Chrome)

I'm running out of ideas.

Is there something else to check?
Anyone having similar problems?

## EDIT   20.02.2016

I followed @Tasos advice to check for latest phone drivers.
I never changed them manually, but after I deinstalled the current driver it worked again like a charm. (no reboot after deinstalling done)

**For anyone having similar issues:**
Run through my checklist.
If everything seems fine but it's still not working: deinstall phone drivers.
If still no good, reboot.
If still no good, install the latest manufacturer drivers.
If still no good, you probably have another problem.

Comment: did you install the USB drivers from the company of those phones?

Comment: @Tasos: No, I havent checked that. Even though it would be mysterious, because it worked before and I havent changed drivers, I will still update them for both devices and test it. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: for my LG mobile i had to install the drivers for the phone because i assume the plug and play generic drivers to read the phones storage dont have certain features hence why when you open dev tools it cant see the phone. its worth to check which drivers are installed anyway.

Comment: @Tasos: Yeah, you was right. Although I didnt have to update or change to the correct driver. It was enough to just deinstall the driver for the phones. I didnt had to reboot after that. It worked instantly after deinstalling the current driver.
Still, it's very strange. I never changed the drivers for the phones, it worked for about half a year, but suddenly they didnt work anymore. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @Tasos advice to **check for latest phone drivers**. I **never changed them manually**, but after I **deinstalled the current driver** it **worked again** like a charm. (no reboot after deinstalling done)

**For anyone having similar issues:**

- Run through my checklist.
- If everything seems fine but it's still not working: deinstall phone drivers.
- If still no good, reboot.
- If still no good, install the latest manufacturer drivers.
- If still no good, you probably have another problem.